# weblogic-maven-plugin appc goal 12.1.3. weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160127]ERROR: Could not delete previous archive

Tags: weblogic12c, weblogic-maven-plugin

If you are experience issues with maven and the appc goal with the maven plugin resulting in:

weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160127]ERROR: Could not delete previous archive

then read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

**Firstly** the order of the application.xml is important

if you are using the maven-ear-plugin, then ensure all of the modules listed are in dependency order in the pom

```
<modules>
   <ejbModule></ejbModule>
</modules>
```

if not ensure that your application.xml is in dependency order

```
  <module>
    <ejb>rng.jar</ejb>
  </module>
```

etc.

To clarify what i mean by dependency order.

If A depends on C, B depends on A, C depends on nothing.
The order of specification should be C, A, B.

**Secondly** it seems there is some kind of validation on having EJB dependencies which are not necessary (you use none of the classes of that EJB). Using the first method I was able to reduce this down to 1 jar not being deleted. After this all of my jars were deleted from the temp directory.

The directory for reference was:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\appcgen_1439472796562_application.ear